# saving data into arraylist in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a for loop which execute 1000 times ! and I want to save the result of each iteration into an arraylist but it does not save the data from the last iteration ! it just clear the whole arraylist in every iteration and add new items to that !

how should I save the whole data ? I would not add any code because it's really complicated and really hard to explain what's going on in the loop . I want to generally know how to solve the problem and be able to save the whole data

Comment: Make sure you're not creating a new list every iteration! Learn how to create a minimal usecase that demonstrates the behavior! We can't really address the problem without knowing what your code does!

Comment: You're going to need to include an extract of your code at least. It's going to be like playing Pin the Tail on the Donkey in the Mariana Trench with a squid attached to your face otherwise.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, if it is as simple as it sounds, then just inititalize the array outside the loop and keep adding to it! i dont see the big deal here! Post the code, and help us help you!

Comment: actually the code is in processing.js which use java language and I need someone who knows that!

Comment: Doesn't matter! We can't just keep guessing! We have no idea what you're doing! What you're doing in the loop is irrelevant, what matters is how/where you create the list, and how you're adding data to it.

Comment: As I said, a minimal usecase that demonstrates the behavior--nothing there is relevant except where you add the data to the list, and the list itself. Note that all the answers are the same, because we were guessing, and at least somewhat off-topic.

Comment: The code is complex because somebody has made it so... Looking at it I can see magic numbers, copy and paste, excessive complexity in a single function, suboptimal choice of list container (i.e. use a Generic if you can) etc. Refactor the code to be clean and maybe the problem will jump out of the page at you.

Comment: that's not my answer ! the problem is how should I use arraylist in processing ! and I'm gonna ask my question in processing.js forum

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `ArrayList` outside of your `for` loop.

Like so

```
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    int result = myFunction(i);
    results.add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would need your code to understand more precisely where does the problem come from but I think it may be because you create a new `ArrayList` within the loop.

Your code should look like this :

```
List list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    data = ...
    list.add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Empty `ArrayList` object out side the for loop.get your object in for loop and add it to list.

```
List<YourClass> list=new ArrayList<YourClass>();

    for(int i=0;i <1000;i++)
    {
        obj=new YourClass();
        list.add(obj);
    }
```

Comment: How does this add useful information not already contained in the two existing answers?